# Swagger-php Annotations for Request Headers

Tags: swagger-php

I am creating a Restful api in php using Slim framework. To document the api's am using Swagger-php Annotations. **How to annotate the Request Headers for a api ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this issue

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/182

try with:

@SWG\Parameter(paramType="header", ...)

Answer (score 10):

This must have changed, because this works for me now:

```
@SWG\Parameter(
  type="string",                                                                                                                                                                              
  name="Authorization",
  in="header",
  required=true)
```

Just in case someone else stumbles along here looking for this.